# Programmatically adding a header image to a wordpress blog page -storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a heavily modified Wordpress site that has, in the past, never utilized the blog feature of Wordpress. The site is an e-commerce site that is using Woocommerce and the Storefront theme. I have installed the Storefront blog customizer and all of that is fine, but the marketing team wants a header image to appear between the site header/nav and the post. Is there an `add_action()` hook that I can use to do this, or does this need to be done in a template file. 
If so, which one....?? 
It is not clear what template is being used with the storefront blog customizer.

Comment: You've got to analyze your theme files to check what possibilities you have. Right now it'd be pure speculation on our part, or with luck someone with the exact theme will read your question...

Answer (score -2):

You can have an external file..

```
//Header.php
function returnHeader()
{
   return '<img id="imgheader" src="img.jpg">';
}
```

Then in your files

```
<?php require_once("Header.php"); ?> 
<div class="header" ><?php returnHeader(); ?></div>
<div class="nav" />
```

Comment: Hmm ok... I actually don't want to replace the header. Probably should have used a better word. This image will sit below the nav on the blog page only, and just serve as a intro the the blog.  Would this still apply?

Comment: i think that i don't understand you..<?php returnHeader(); ?> will insert html code